# How do I keep my My Sites from prompting users for credentials?

Tags: active-directory, my-site

Currently on my SharePoint 2010 install the My Sites section is roped off on a sub-domain (port 80) of the main site collection.  Whenever anyone opens the main site it automatically detects their username through AD and logs them in without prompting them.  If they try to enter the My Sites sub-domain they are prompted to enter their username and password.

How do I get the My Sites site collection to act like the main site collection in regards to user credentials?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely it is because the browser is not detecting that the subsite is in the proper domain.  in IE, this is accomplished by making sure that everything that is *.intranetdomain.com is in the "Local Intranet" zone, which is usually done via Policy.  It can also be done manually by going to Tools-Options-Internet settings-Security-Local Intranet-Sites-Advanced

Comment: What steps can I take to change this with Central Administration?

Comment: That is not really a Central Administration issue as the passing or ignoring of credentials is a decision made by the browser itself.  In Central Admin, all you can do is ensure that you are using Windows Authentication for the site, which you are apparently already doing.

Comment: So do I have to use GP to set the browsers for every employee to work properly?

Comment: That is what most companies do.  Just make sure to use the wildcard (i.e. *.intranetdomain.com) so that you don't have to update the policy for every subsite.  If you have a higher level domain structure, like subdomain.domain.company.com, then set the policy to put *.company.com in the Intranet Zone.  Whichever makes the most sense for your organization.

Comment: Sweet, will this work for mapped drives as well?  Right now I've got a document library in my personal My Site mapped to J:\ and every time I boot my machine it tells me that it couldn't reconnect all of my network drives.  Will this correct that issue as well?

Comment: That is really beyond my area of expertise but my gut feeling is that the change would not affect that. However, an easy way to check that would be to simply make the change to your local machine and reboot.

Comment: WRT Mapped drives: It depends on what your OS is. If you're running Windows Vista or Windows 7, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943280. Putting in the required registry info fixed the credential prompting for us. Windows XP users were never prompted for their credentials for mapped drives.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I would go for it is implementing Kerberos. That, combined with browser settings to enable "Intranet Token caching" should do it for you in a blink.